# Make DialogBox wait for user action and return boolean in GWT

Tags: gwt

How can I make DialogBox (confirmation message and OK & Cancel buttons) wait for user action and return boolean result (true is OK was clicked, false otherwise)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to use [`Window.confirm`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html#confirm(java.lang.String)), which "Displays a message in a modal dialog box, along with the standard 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons."

Answer (score 3):

Other way would be to split your code and put all that which has to be executed after ok/cancel click in a callback. Execute the callback in the ok/cancel handlers of the dialog box.